# Pick one string from an Array of 4 strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, random, char

I have this kind of array with these values declared in this way :

```
static char forecast[4][150] = {"Sunny","Cloudly","Heavy rain", "Ice"};
```

now, I want to pick up randomly one string among the other and to do this I did this:

```
        forecast = forecast[rand()%4];
```

but I'm receiving this error:

```
error: assignment to expression with array type
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can't assign to arrays and the code makes no sense regardless. Use `char* another_variable = forecast[rand()%4];`

Comment: Because strings are immutable arrays (don't change in given strings), you are basically trying to change the value of a string with the randomizer. You will also want to consider `srand` to have a randomizer for any time you execute the program.